# Single query command

Tags: mysql

I am putting the csv file content in the database.
When I am running below command manually..its working fine..but when i put in in command prompt below single query, its not running.

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -hlocalhost -e "LOAD DATA INFILE "C:\csvfile.csv" 
INTO TABLE test.LoadedEmployee FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY '' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" STARTING BY ''"
```

FYI ..Manual syntax which is working:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -hlocalhost 
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:\csvfile.csv" INTO TABLE test.LoadedEmployee 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" STARTING BY ''
```

Comment: what you mean by when I run this manually...?if you have to run it manually u are using command promt rite?

Comment: Yes I am running the querry manually from command prompt...When I put the querry in a script and then try to run the script it throws error : ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\n'. Pls help

Comment: are you using .bat file to create a script?

Comment: yes..using a bat file...

Comment: I have tried below things,
1) mysql -uroot -proot -hlocalhost -e "LOAD DATA INFILE "C:\csvfile.csv" INTO TABLE test.LoadedEmployee FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" STARTING BY ''"
Error : ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\n'.
2) Instead of -e I tried putting <
Error :The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load CSV file then try this: FYI This will ignore the first line - the header.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: It is still not working..When I am manually running the querry which I have provided, its running fine..but when I am putting in the script and running through the command prompt the same querry is giving below error:ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\n'. Please help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
load data local infile 'urfile.csv' into table yourtablefields terminated by ','
enclosed by ''  ESCAPED BY '\\'  lines terminated by '\n'
(col1, col2, col3...)
```

Here put the actual column names at the end in above script.Also put this script in a .bat file and save it where is your .csv file is located.Now open comman prompt and navigate to the the directory where your mysql is installed from there run the batch file.

Comment: Still it is throwing error. I have edited below querry in my script.
mysql -uroot -proot -hlocalhost < "LOAD DATA INFILE "C:\csvfile.csv" INTO TABLE test.LoadedEmployee FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (Empid,Empname,Compy,DOB,DOJ)"

Error : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: dont do anything with the script just copy and paste it into .bat file.No need of double quotes and single quotes

Comment: I tried one more option: First I have kept a sql query in one file "6sql.sql":
LOAD DATA INFILE "csvfile.csv" INTO TABLE test.LoadedEmployee FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n" STARTING BY ''

And then executed the command from comd prompt as below :
mysql -uroot -pdbase -h127.0.0.1 < "C:\6sql.sql"

Throwing error : ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown MySQL server host 'STARTING' (0)